# How does the navigation work in TurtleBot

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I would like to ask about the technique that used for Mapping and navigation. dose it build a 3D map and if it how builds it and how uses it for navigation.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12112/how-does-the-navigation-work-in-turtlebot/) by [Said](https://answers.ros.org/users/1450/said/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2011-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It uses the ROS navigation stack documented on the [ros wiki navigation page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-12-12**:
As mentioned by @mwise_wg and @Stefan Kohlbrecher the 3D data is downsampled to 2D data.  Please don't ask follow up questions in "answers" to this question.  This is a directed question and answer not a forum.  If you have a new follow up question, please pose it as it's own question.

**Comment by [Said](https://answers.ros.org/users/1450/said/) on 2011-11-29**:
Hi Many thanks for answer

But it is most likely 2D navigation , so why TurtleBot uses kinect which is RGB-D scanner??

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TurtleBot uses the ROS navigation stack. The navigation stack requires a 2D laser scan to work. To create a 2D laser scan the kinect point cloud data is converted to a laser scan using the [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan) package in the turtlebot stack.

The pointcloud_to_laserscan package contains a nodelet called cloud_to_scan which samples the data in a region around specified height in the point cloud. Then given a set of points in an angular slice it returns the min range value for that angular slice. See the [code](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/b9d718d0d4ad/pointcloud_to_laserscan/src/cloud_to_scan.cpp) for more details on how a point cloud is converted to a laser scan.

The TurtleBot localization primer might also be instructive: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C92bxCr05Gs

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Said](https://answers.ros.org/users/1450/said/) on 2011-12-13**:
Many Thanks